# why can't i cancel job in kotlin coroutines?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

this is when I use the delay function

```
    @Test
    fun testJob(){
        runBlocking {
            val job = GlobalScope.launch {
                println("Start Coroutine ${Date()}")
                delay(1000)
                println("End Coroutine ${Date()}")
            }
            job.cancel()
            delay(2000)
        }
    }
```

this is when i use the Thread.sleep function

```
    @Test
    fun testJob(){
        runBlocking {
            val job = GlobalScope.launch {
                println("Start Coroutine ${Date()}")
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                println("End Coroutine ${Date()}")
            }
            job.cancel()
            delay(2000)
        }
    }
```

why cancel() can't work when i use Thread.sleep ?

Comment: Coroutines are only cancelled when they reach a suspension point. Thread.sleep is not a suspend function so it simply blocks the thread. Your coroutine is not cancellation cooperative because it has no suspension points.

Answer (score 2):

Thread.sleep() is a blocking method, while delay() is a suspend one. Kotlin coroutines may run on a single thread asynchronously, there is a state machine inside, which switches between suspend calls, but when you call Thread.sleep(), it blocks the entire thread.

Answer (score 0):

delay()'s doc says: "*Delays coroutine for a given time **without blocking a thread** and resumes it after a specified time.*"
But when you call Thread.sleep(), you are delaying the thread itself, which prevents everything else from running on that thread, even other coroutines.